# Django/Python Model/Form class design

Tags: python, django, relational-database

Can someone provide advice on the best way to structure my model and form classes. While I do have 25+ years experience in software development (primarily scientific visualization), I don't have much experience in relational database design.

Here is what I want to do...

I'm trying to develop a Django web app for my tennis club for scheduling team matches, I'm planning on the having the following classes:

- Team - will contain a captain, list of players and a list of matches
- Player - will contain the players name, cell, email
- Match - will contain a date, opponent, location and result

Now, here's where the real question comes in...I want each player to be able to indicate their availability for each match (Yes, No, Maybe), and I want to be able to assign each player a position for each match (there are 2 singles courts and 3 doubles courts).

I would prefer this be in a simple table format that looks something like this:
[image]

where each cell in the body of the table is a drop down, allowing the user to choose Y, N, or ? (only for themselves), or the team captain to choose S1,S2,D1,D2, or D3 (for everybody)

So, my question, is how do I represent this in a Django model class? And how do I create a form to display it and collect the changes made by the user?

I'm using Python 2.7.6 and Django 1.10.

Answers to questions in in comments:

- S1, S2, D1, D2, D3 are court assignments for a given match(we play 2 singles courts and 3 doubles courts)
- The captain is also a player on the team
- A person may play on several teams
- A person may captain several teams
- I would like to handle any number of teams (likely 10 or so each season)
- An opponent is just a string (i.e. the name of the opposing team)

I have made an attempt at this, with the models basically looking like this:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='')

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player)
    captain = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name="captain", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Week(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    opponent = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class PlayerWeek(models.Model):
    week = models.ForeignKey(Week, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignment = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

User is from django.contrib.auth.models

assignment will be Y, N, ?, S1, S2, D1, D2, D3

I think this captures the relationships I need, but I have no idea how to render the form or collect the user input.

Comment: What are S1, S2, D1, D2, or D3? Are these positions like single & doubles? Maybe you also want to consider adding a `Court` model which can have the singles or doubles defined for that court. Then a `Match` can be linked to a court.

Comment: That's a bit too broad of a question. I can understand the models design partis not obvious for someone with no relational db experience, but for the second part of the question you may want to first give it a try by yourself (django is fairly well documented) and come back with more specific questions.

Comment: Is the "captain" one of the players ? Can a "player" belong to more than one "team" ? Can a "captain" leads more than one "team" ? How many "team" do you want to handle ? What's an "opponent" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my design using django formsets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/

I ended up with 3 forms (TeamForm, PlayerForm, and PlayerWeekForm), with the PlayerForm instantiated in the TeamForm, and the PlayerWeekForm instantiated in the PlayerForm.

The resulting screen looks like this:
[image]

So, to be complete, the view looks like this:

```
def detailform(request, team_id):
    team = get_object_or_404(Team, pk=team_id)
    print team_id
    print team
    PlayerFormSet = formset_factory(PlayerForm, formset=BaseFormSet, extra=0)

    team_players = team.players.all()

    player_data = [{'name' : p.user.first_name+" "+p.user.last_name, 'player' : p } for p in team_players]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.POST
        pi = 0
        for player in team.players.all():
            i=0
            for week in team.week_set.all():
                wd = request.POST.getlist('form-{}-available'.format(i))
                print wd
                pws_t = player.playerweek_set.get(player=player, week=week );
                pws = get_object_or_404(PlayerWeek, pk=pws_t.pk)
                pws.available = wd[pi]
                pws.save()
                i=i+1
            pi=pi+1


    player_formset = PlayerFormSet(initial=player_data)
    team_form = TeamForm(team=team, formset=player_formset)

    context = { 'team_form' : team_form, 'team' : team }

    return render(request, 'dtm/team_form.html', context)
```

and the forms look like this:

```
class PlayerWeekForm(forms.Form):

    AVAILABLE_CHOICES = ( ('Y', 'Yes'), ('N', 'No'), ('?', '?'), ('S1', 'S1'), ('S2', 'S2'), ('D1', 'D1'), ('D2', 'D2'), ('D3', 'D3'))    
    available = forms.ChoiceField(choices=AVAILABLE_CHOICES)


class PlayerForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.player = kwargs['initial']['player']

        super(PlayerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['name'] = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput(), disabled=True)

        PlayerWeekFormSet = formset_factory(PlayerWeekForm, formset=BaseFormSet, extra=0)
        pwdata = [{'available' : pwf.available_type} for pwf in self.player.playerweek_set.all()]
        self.playerweek_formset = PlayerWeekFormSet(initial = pwdata)

class TeamForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.team = kwargs.pop('team', None)
        self.player_formset = kwargs.pop('formset', None)

        super(TeamForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['name'] = forms.CharField(max_length=30,initial = self.team.name, widget=forms.TextInput(), disabled=True)
```

Ultimately I will subclass BaseFormSet as necessary to do validation on the formset.